# Dar formato a un PDF asp.net c# con iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas Tardes .

estoy realizando una exportancion a pdf para eso estoy usando **iTextSharp** por lo cual lo que yo quisiera esque la cabecera sea centrado por la que ya lo realice:

- NumeroCuota
- FechaVencimiento
- cuota
- AmortizacionCapital
- Interes
- Saldo

y el resto debe ser de la posicion derecha

este es mi codigo actual :

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        //To Export all pages

                        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
                        this.BindGrid();

                        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

                        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);

                        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                        pdfDoc.Open();



                        Font LineBreak = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", size: 14);

                       // pdfDoc.Add(img);
                       // img.ScaleAbsolute(159f, 159f);

                        pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("SIMULADOR DE CREDITOS"));
                        pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("\n\n", LineBreak));
                        pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("CRONOGRAMA DE CREDITOS"));

                        pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("\n\n", LineBreak));

                        htmlparser.Parse(sr);

                        pdfDoc.Close();

                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Simulador_Credito.pdf");
                        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                        Response.End();
                    }
}
}
```

Bueno la cabecera la lo ordene al centro pero todo se centra pero yo quisiera que al cuerpo sean derecha .

lo realice con este codigo

```
 e.Row.Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            e.Row.Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            e.Row.Cells[3].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            e.Row.Cells[4].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            e.Row.Cells[5].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
```

Esto me generando a la actualidad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para centrar cualquier palabra tenemos que crear una variable y agregar la propiedad alignment:

- 0: Izquierda
- 1: Centro
- 2: Derecha

al documento que se va exportar

```
   var para = new Paragraph("FINANCIERA QAPAQ");
                        para.Alignment=1;
                        para.Font.Size = 18;
                        pdfDoc.Add(para);
```